# VS Code - How to add/remove/edit multiple tags' attributes

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Was wondering if Vs Code offered any way to update multiple instances of a tag, let's say a group of li elements in my case. I would like to transform this:

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
```

into this:

```
<li class="list_item">Item 1</li>
<li class="list_item">Item 2</li>
<li class="list_item">Item 3</li>
<li class="list_item">Item 4</li>
```

I tried using the native "Update Tag" function, but it somehow seemed broken / could only update the name of the tag, without being capable of adding/removing/editing attributes and their values.

Guess I could resort to a good old find and replace but I would assume VS Code could offer a nice tool to do that natively. Looks like it was at some point intended with "Using Tag", if I refer to that 2013 commit:

https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/commit/15bb514f82e72bb4752e546814aeaedf132dbb3a

Thanks!

Comment: Did the solution below achieve what you were asking for?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag yohr answer! Probably the best native tool I can use to achieve thus task, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS code you can hold `opt + cmd` or `ctrl + alt` then use the down and up arrows and the line cursor will duplicate to each line at the position you want.

You can then type across multiple lines.

[image]

As shown in the site below; you also have the option for multi cursor editing as well:

https://kencenerelli.wordpress.com/2018/03/25/visual-studio-code-multi-line-and-multi-cursor-editing/

Answer (score 3):

Windows:
Ctrl+Shift+L

Mac:
Cmd+Shift+L or Cmd+Ctrl+G

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers do the trick. No doubt in that! But if you use VSCode (Not sure if this is applicable to other IDEs) and are interested in another trick that can be used when you are just writing your script and want to save time and avoid writing multiple repetitive lines, use [Emmet Abbreviations](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/):

```
li.list_item{Item $}*4
```

After writing the last "4" down, there should be a suggestion pupped up to you something like following:

[image: Emmet Abberviation]

After clicking on that suggestion you will end up having the following results:

```
<li class="list_item">Item 1</li>
<li class="list_item">Item 2</li>
<li class="list_item">Item 3</li>
<li class="list_item">Item 4</li>
```